# How can i connect to a separate server and parse its JSON response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i need to connect to another server we manage and have it's results (in JSON format) processed by rails... how can I do it ?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean connect client side using JavaScript / AJAX, or connect server side using ruby?

Comment: server side using ruby - although using javascript/ajax might also work by dynamically inserting script tags .. but i think it has to be server side since it will still involve querying info from the database..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the [NET/HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html) library, you can get the content of a distant file.
Then with the [JSON](http://flori.github.com/json/) library you can parse a json string into a hash.

```
def get_datas
    url = URI.parse("http://www.example.com/page.json")
    res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
        http.get(url.path)
    }
    JSON.parse res.body
end
```

Comment: I'm trying the following: `data = response.body
    result = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(data)` but how do i store this to an ActiveRecord ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [ActiveResource](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html) as a model if you like that kind of interface:

```
class Thing < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://api.example.com:3000/"
  self.format = :json
  self.element_name = "thing"
end
```

This might be more than you need, though, as often Net::HTTP and the JSON library will do the job.